# Can't change binding values of custom element in code behind

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am trying to create a Custom Element that allows me to collapse itself from a simple click delegate, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have this code in my js file

```
import {inject, bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class DataGridCustomElement {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneTime }) columns = [];
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneTime }) items = [];
  @bindable() collpased = true;


  collapseClick() {
    this.collapsed = !this.collpased;
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML file

```
<template>
  <require from='./data-grid.css'></require>
  <div class="collapse-arrow" click.delegate="collapseClick()">
    <span class="collapse-icon glyphicon ${collapsed ? 'glyphicon-plus' : 'glyphicon-minus'}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span>Order Lines</span>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse-block" css="${collapsed ? 'display:none;' : 'display:block;'}">
    <table class="data-grid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td repeat.for="column of columns">
            ${column.title}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="item of items">
          <td repeat.for="column of columns">
            ${item[column.propertyName]}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

The crazy thing is it just doesn't seem to at all. It shows `collapsed` as being `false` from the get go, even though I set it to true in the class.

I am calling it like so

```
<data-grid columns.bind="invoiceColumns" items.bind="lineData"></data-grid>
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something about Custom Elements?

Comment: Does it work to remove the empty parenthesis after `@bindable` in `@bindable() collpased = true;`?  I've always used it with no parenthesis unless you're adding details.

Comment: Also, you have a typo in `this.collapsed = !this.collpased;`.  Is that also in your code?

Comment: @LStarky Well... that's embarrassing... Sometimes you need a second set of eyes, though. Thanks!

Comment: Yep... been there many times!  I'm glad it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution.  You have a typo in `this.collapsed = !this.collpased;`.

Comment: typo based bugs are the easiest to fix. great catch @Lstarky!